# Wiring up a ILI9341 TFT Screen + Touch

Tags: gpio, hardware, screen

I've bought a ILI9341 TFT LCD Screen + Touch to my Raspberry pi. The screen is the MI0283QT-9A "TFT PROTO", from Mikroeletronika. [Here is the link to the producer's page](http://www.mikroe.com/add-on-boards/display/tft-proto/). It has an ILI9341 chipset, according to the producer.

I searched around the web about how to wire it up and make it run on Raspberry pi. The little screen accepts 5 interface modes: 16-bit, 8-bit, 18-bit, 9-bit and SPI. To save some GPIO pins on Raspberry Pi, I thought I could use the SPI Interface mode.

I found [this](http://lallafa.de/blog/2013/03/watterott-display-on-raspberry-pi/) site where a guy hook the same type of screen on a Rpi. The thing is, his pins are different from mine!

He writes the following pin connection:

```
Name               Raspi             Display Board
+5V                2+4               3+4
GND                6                 1+2
CS_DISP            26 (CE1)          7
RST_DISP           16 (GPIO23)       6
LED_DISP           18 (GPIO24)       5
MOSI               19                8
MISO               21                9
SCLK               23                10
```

I don't have those pins on my LCD board. In fact, the screen is driven with 3.3v, not 5. The following are my pins:

```
  LEDA | | LEDK
   IM1 | | IM0
   IM3 | | IM2
  DB17 | | RST
  DB15 | | DB16
  DB13 | | DB14
  DB11 | | DB12
   DB9 | | DB10
   DB7 | | DB8
   DB5 | | DB6
   DB3 | | DB4
   DB1 | | DB2
   SND | | DB0
   SDI | | SDO
WR/SCL | | RD
    CS | | RS
   GND | | FMARK
    y+ | | x+
    y- | | x-
   GND | | 3.3v
```

Now, I read that MOSI is SDO, and MISO is SDI, but what GND do I use? Where is the CLK, CS, RESET (I think mine is RST). And his driver will work for me (without frying my Rpi, that is)?

And what about the touch feature? How do I hook-up it? How can I find a driver for it? Any help is fine!

Thanks a lot, in advance.

Comment: See here for how to get the touch screen working: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-28-inch-resistive-touchscreen-display-raspberry-pi/touchscreen-install-and-calibrate I am not if this will work for you, but may help

Comment: Thank you for helping, but my LCD is quite different from this Adafruit plung-n-play screen, even if the chipset it's the same. This guide doesn't specify what communication interface the screen uses, nor the pinout info that I need. But it's quite a good guide, and I can use it's later software configurations to improve visibility and video quality, so I thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I used this guide today http://marcosgildavid.blogspot.gr/2014/02/getting-ili9341-spi-screen-working-on.html and it worked!

Be sure to follow the links and especially the wiki https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki.

Good luck!