# HELP, undo code that was for another touch LCD screen. Now it won't boot all the way

Tags: pi-3, boot, pi-3b+, lcd

How can I undo the sudo code that was run with the wrong type of LCD "...-show"
The system boots to a certain point and then just does not continue. Ive tried mounting the micro sd and see if I can change to the designated screen, but can't find where or how without formatting the drive and reinstalling the system
The code that was used was:

```
sudo rm -rf LCD-show 
git clone https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show.git 
chmod -R 755 LCD-show 
cd LCD-show/
sudo ./LCD35-show
```

but should have been:

```
git clone https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show.git
chmod -R 755 LCD-show
cd LCD-show/
sudo ./MPI3508-show
```

https://trickiknow.com/raspberry-pi-3-complete-tutorial-2018-lets-get-started/

Comment: You may try reformatting the SD Card and burning a fresh version of Raspbian, if you don't want to buy another card.

Answer (score 2):

***Question***

> Rpi can no longer boot after installing wrong LCD driver.  How to fix?

***Answer***

*Short answer*

A quick and dirty fix is:

> 1. Use a new SD card with a freshly downloaded Raspbian image, without any new LCD driver installed.
> 2. Then install your correct LCD driver.

*Long answer*

You can fiddle with the Raspbian config files to remove wrongly installed the LCD driver, but that is very messy.  You might might to read the references below to see how tricky it is.

/ to continue, ...

***References***

[Banngood Geekcreit 3.5" 320 X 480 TFT Touch LCD For Rpi](https://www.banggood.com/3_5-Inch-320-X-480-TFT-LCD-Display-Touch-Board-For-Raspberry-Pi-2-Model-B-RPI-B-p-1023432.html?utm_campaign=12991202_1023432&utm_content=2791&p=QZ080112991202201708&cur_warehouse=USA)

[Banngood Geekcreit 3.5" 320 X 480 TFT Touch LCD Manual and Driver](https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show)

[TrickShow Rpi3 Complete Tutorial 2018 – 2018jan31](https://trickiknow.com/raspberry-pi-3-complete-tutorial-2018-lets-get-started/)

[YouTube TrickShow Rpi 3.5" Touch LCD + LiPo Power Bank](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=MorJLzybb3I)

[How to install ILI9341 LCD Kernel Module Part 1](https://github.com/juj/fbcp-ili9341)

[How to install ILI9341 LCD Kernel Module Part 2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98549/lcd-tft-screen-2-8-ili9341-spi-connect?noredirect=1#comment161375_98549)

Comment: You are welcome.  Have a nice project!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are running **Raspbian Stretch**. If so you can use **systemd** to try to boot into rescue or emergency mode. In [systemd.special — Special systemd units](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html) you will find for

> **rescue.target**
>
> A special target unit that pulls in the base system (including system mounts) and spawns a rescue shell. Isolate to this target in order to administer the system in single-user mode with all file systems mounted but with no services running, except for the most basic. Compare with emergency.target, which is much more reduced and does not provide the file systems or most basic services.
>   [..]
>   Use the "systemd.unit=rescue.target" kernel command line option to boot into this mode.

So pull out the SD Card of the RasPi, make a backup image from it on another computer and then edit `cmdline.txt` on the boot partition. Just append `systemd.unit=rescue.target` at the end of the line and boot it in your RasPi.

You can also try to boot with `systemd.unit=emergency.target` in `cmdline.txt` but as explained in *systemd.special* that's much more limited in execution of programs.

With some luck you may be able to fix your problem.

Comment: @user103985 Glad to help you :-) Could you fix your problem? If so it would be nice if you could accept the answer by ticking the check on  the left side. This will finish the question and show other users that it has a solution.

Comment: Haven't tested just yet, but will in a bit.