# How to connect Raspberry Pi 4 to sparkfun SSD1306 / SSD1309 OLED transparent display?

Tags: camera, display, setup

I just got the an OLED transparent Display from Sparkfun and I want to make it run, I youtube it but didn't found anything. Please help me with that.

Comment: which one? https://de.aliexpress.com/store/group/2-3-to-5-5-OLED-LCD/224898_251993809.html

Comment: Or one of these? https://shop468430569.world.taobao.com/search.htm?q=OLED&navigator=all&_input_charset=&spm=a21bp.7806943.20151106.1

Comment: For newbies, I recommend SSD1306 12864: https://www.aliexpress.com/ssd1306-oled-128x64_reviews.html

Comment: I want to connect this one.
https://let-elektronik.dk/shop/1190-monokrom/15173--transparent-graphical-oled-breakout-qwiic/?gclid=Cj0KCQiArdLvBRCrARIsAGhB_szUUJ4FS1Zv4qwi4V2a8PHBjtgguriVDzcH5qQQG_7maHsB3XXL8CUaAroLEALw_wcB

Comment: Ah, your OLED is SSD1309, which is a bit harder to play with the more popular 1306: AliExpress SSD1309 OLEDs
https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-ssd1309-oled-display.html.  Anyway, I would suggest to first try this driver: (1) SSD1306/SSD1309 Drivers Python: 
https://luma-oled.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.  Please let me know if you have any DIY experience of (1) Rpi GPIO blinking a LED, Rpi buster Thonny python 3.7, (2) SPI, or (3) I2C. Then I know if I should talk in Rpi newbie or ninja language.

Comment: However, newbie or ninja, you must first check out the follow SparkFun YT and Hookup guide: (1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=7&v=vzFuVbxBfXI&feature=emb_logo
(2) https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/transparent-graphical-oled-breakout-hookup-guide

Comment: SSD309 OLED talks I2C or SPI.  The SparkFun YT Doom guy recommends to try I2C, but then says you must SPI for fast action. All Arduino ok doomers talks SPI, and would LOL at low IQ Rpi I2C guys. However, I2C is easier to handle, but be prepared to upgrade to SPI sooner or later: https://imgur.com/gallery/AB82EPK.

Comment: SparkFun OLED Hookup guide is newbie friendly to learn how to do the wring for I2C or SPI. However, their software example is only for Arduino. For Rpi Python, you need to learn by the luma.oled tutorial which also very newbie friendly on I2C/SPI introduction, how to install drivers etc.  One good thing is their API.  You might like to read the API on setting up the display. Please let me know if you don't know anything there difficult:  https://luma-oled.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-documentation.html

Comment: In case you find Luma OLED tutorial still hard to understand, you might like to also read similar tutorials for LCD.  I would recommend the popular LCD drivers such as st7789 (Pyromoni has good tutorials), ili9341-xpt2046 (touch screen, but very tedious) drivers. Again, please let me know if you which have more special user requirements. I will give the links next comment.  Happy learning and cheers:)

Comment: ST7789, ILI9341 LCD Tutorials:
(1) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104846/how-to-connect-st7789-lcd-to-spi-bus-1-as-2nd-screen
(2) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99187/is-0-96-inch-display-st7735s-working-with-raspberry-pi
(3) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98549/rpi3b-rpi4b-ili9341-xpt2046-spi-2-8-touch-tft-lcd-connection-driver-problem/98557#98557
(4) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104600/artillery-ili9341-3-2-lcd-touch-screen-white-display-and-driver-problem/104610#104610