# Is there a screen that will fit the Raspberry Pi Zero W that doesn't use I2C

Tags: gpio, pi-zero-w, screen

I've been using the Adafruit PiOLED which causes some issues with the PiSugar 2 battery I'm using. Because of this, I'm looking for recommendations on a screen that doesn't use the I2C protocol. I'd prefer one with no touch screen if possible.

Comment: Ah, there are in general two kinds of communication protocols for LCD/LED screens: I2C and SPI. For Rpi, there is a special interface for screens. You can google Rpi to find out more.

Comment: Gotcha, any recommendations for an SPI screen? I'm currently looking at this one: https://www.adafruit.com/product/4393

Comment: To add some context about the one I posted, I'm worried about using it because it is wired to use I2C but only for the STEMMA QT / Qwiic connector. If I omit that cable, I'm worried it will still cause issues

Comment: I only know that Qwiic is SparkFun thing, but it is a physical non standard, so you can do your rewiring, similar to what I mess around RS232/serial standards with my own wiring hardware (yes, no nothing about DB9, double shielding etc, just cheapy 2.54 DuPont connectors), in  my toy projects (115kBd, home environment).

Comment: I have posted a couple of answers in this forum on SPI/I2C LCD/LED displays. This is an example: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98549/rpi3b-rpi4b-ili9341-xpt2046-spi-2-8-touch-tft-lcd-connection-driver-problem. I vaguely remember my last post is about Piromoni SPI display which I think is good.  I usually follow tutorials from AdaFruit and WaveShare, less frequently but more recently Piromoni and sparkFun.

Comment: BTW, I do find I2C OLED OK. In case you change your mind, you might like to check out how I mess around with little I2C OLEDs: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106482/rpi3b-ssd1306-oled-i2c-interface-problem. Cheers.