# Rpi pico micropython ssd1306 OSError: 5

Tags: i2c, pi-pico, micropython

Solved

I have .91inch 128x32 pixel oled display. [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FMDB6TR)

im following Tom's Hardware tutorial [here](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/oled-display-raspberry-pi-pico)

I'm using Thonny on windows 10

ive basically copy and pasted from Tom's hardware

```
from machine import Pin, I2C
from ssd1306 import SSD1306_I2C

i2c=I2C(0,sda=Pin(0), scl=Pin(1), freq=400000)
oled = SSD1306_I2C(128, 64, i2c)

oled.text("Tom's Hardware", 0, 0)
oled.show()
```

I named the file "main.py"

I have the ssd1306 micropython package.
when i try to run it i get the following message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 17, in <module>
  File "/lib/ssd1306.py", line 110, in __init__
  File "/lib/ssd1306.py", line 36, in __init__
  File "/lib/ssd1306.py", line 71, in init_display
  File "/lib/ssd1306.py", line 115, in write_cmd
OSError: 5
```

I honestly dont know what this is trying to say. i googled "OSError 5" and the only solutions that i could find were to  add a delay between the initiation and the first write to the i2c device. that didnt work.

[image: this is an image of the ssd1306 that i chose in thonny]

does anyone know how to fix this error?

thank you.

SOLVED:
it has been some time since i posted this question,, but this is what i found. errno5 means that the pico couldnt see the oled on the i2c interface. my oled was broken. i can no longer use the module manager for the ssd1306 library, but i could just include one i found online. I dont remember exactly the library that i looked up, but if asked, i can share the file.

Many thanks to tlfong01 for helping me find the issue even if we couldlnt find the solution. it wasnt until a few months after i took a break that i could solve the issue

Comment: #Zeno, Welcome and nice to meet you.  Ah, let me see. Please let everybody know which SSD1306 you are testing, and which tutorial you are following. ***Two links would help a lot.*** Cheers.

Comment: I searched my old files and found a setup record, as shown in Appendix A below. Please confirm your device is exactly the same as mine. So I would tailor my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have added a couple of references to my answer. I would suggest you to skim them and perhaps also listed some references in your answer. This shows the research work you have done, and other readers would upvote you. At least you should show that you are reading Tom's Hardware columns and give the link in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

***Question***

*How can Rpi Pico Micropython Talk To I2C LCD SSD1306?*

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***Answer***

***Update 2021apr08hkt1233***

I found the 0.91" OLED a bit tricky to detect.  I need to make the the wiring short, not to load two or more devices.  I also found I2C Bus 1 better than Bus 1.  Anyway, I used Tom's Hardware's short program and found it OK, though not stable.

---

[image: oled 091 1]

---

***Short Answer***

1. It is pretty likely that Pico Thonny Python's error message "***OSError: 5***" is similar to Rpi Os's "***OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error***"
2. ***Errno 121*** usually occurs when running an I2C python program with the following situation:

   2.1  The hardware wiring connection is bad, eg,

   2.1.1 Forget to plug/connect the cable,

   2.1.2 Too long cabling, eg, over 30cm,

   2.1.2 I2C frequency too high, over 400kHz,

   2.1.3 I2C device, eg. I2C I2C MCP23017, which is sensitive to noise,

   2.1.4 I2C bus overloaded, with more than 4 devices, causing bus capacitance over 400pF.

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***Long Answer***

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***References***

(1) [Solomon OLED Display Catalog - Solomon Tech](https://www.solomon-systech.com/product-category/oled-display/)

(2) [Solomon OLED Driver IC Product Sheet - Solomon Tech](https://www.solomon-systech.com/wp-content/themes/solomon-systech/documents/product-catalogs/oled-driver-ic.pdf)

(3) [Solomon SSD1306 Product Sheet - Solomon Tech](https://www.solomon-systech.com/product/ssd1306/)

(4) [SSD1306 OLED Display Module Product Spec - Denstron/Farnell](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/609753.pdf)

(5) [SSD1306 Tutorial - Components101](https://components101.com/displays/oled-display-ssd1306)

(6) [How to Use an OLED Display With Raspberry Pi Pico - Les Pounder, Tom's Hardware, 2021feb28](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/oled-display-raspberry-pi-pico)

(7) [Luma.OLED API Doc for SSD1306, SSD1309, SSD1322, SSD1325, SSD1327, SSD1331, SSD1351 and SH1106API OLED](https://luma-oled.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-documentation.html)

(8) [Rpi3B SSD1306 OLED I2C Interface Problem (with debugged Hello World program) - tlfong01 Rpi.SE Asked 2019dec21, Viewed 799 times](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106482/rpi3b-ssd1306-oled-i2c-interface-problem)

(9) [Raspberry Pi Pico + 128x64 I2C SSD1306 OLED (MicroPython) Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vVS4gFI5gjM)

(10) [Raspberry Pi Pico + 128x64 I2C SSD1306 OLED (MicroPython) Tutorial](https://helloraspberrypi.blogspot.com/2021/01/raspberry-pi-pico-128x64-i2c-ssd1306.html)

(11) [SSD1306 OLED Display Module Catalog - AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-ssd1306-oled.html)

---

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - Old SSD1306 Setup Record*

---

[image: ssd1306 test 01]

---

*Appendix B - Installing Rpi Pico MicroPython OLED SSD1306 Library - Tom's Hardware*

(6) [How to Use an OLED Display With Raspberry Pi Pico - Les Pounder, Tom's Hardware, 2021feb28](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/oled-display-raspberry-pi-pico)

6. Click on Tools > Manage Packages to open Thonny’s package manager for Python libraries.
7. Type “***ssd1306***” in the search bar and click “***Search on PyPI***”.
8. Click on “***micropython-ssd1306***” in the returned results and then click on Install. This will copy the library to a folder, lib on the Pico.
9. Click Close to return to the main interface.

---

*Note - Only partial installed, with error code 1*

[image: ssd1306 install error 1]

---

*Update 2021apr03hkt1528*

I installed ssd1308 second time and had good luck.

---

[image: ssd1306 install ok]

---

*Appendix C - Pico version of Rpi4B OS buster's command "i2cdetect -y 1"*

Introduction

I am using the Pico Thonny Python function to detect and list the I2C devices on I2C bus 1 and 2.  The following sample output show two i2c pcf8574 devices are detected.

Note - The Thonny sample is badly formatted in RpiSE here. So I am going to use PenZu to write a better formatted file (to be include in next Appendix D).

```
MicroPython v1.14 on 2021-02-02; Raspberry Pi Pico with RP2040
```

Type "help()" for more information.

> > > %Run -c $EDITOR_CONTENT
> > > Begin scanI2cBuses(), tlfong01  2021apr03hkt1431, ...
> > >
> > > > > > > > > > Begin testPcf8574(), ... >>>>>>>>>>

*** Set up I2C bus list [i2cBus0, i2cBus1] ***

*** I2C Bus List Config ***
I2C Bus Num = 0  Bus nick name = Amy     Frequency = 100 kHz  sdaPin = 0  sclPin = 1
I2C Bus Num = 1  Bus nick name = Betty   Frequency = 400 kHz  sdaPin = 2  sclPin = 3

*** I2c Device Dict ***
i2cDevNum = 0   DeviceName = PCF8574 #1  NickName = Connie    I2cBusNum = 0  I2cDevAddr = 0x23
i2cDevNum = 1   DeviceName = PCF8574 #2  NickName = Daisy     I2cBusNum = 1  I2cDevAddr = 0x24
i2cDevNum = 2   DeviceName = LCD2004 #1  NickName = Emily     I2cBusNum = 0  I2cDevAddr = 0x27
i2cDevNum = 3   DeviceName = LCD1602 #1  NickName = Fanny     I2cBusNum = 1  I2cDevAddr = 0x22

*** Scan and print I2C devices I2C bus list [i2cBus0, i2cBus1] ***
I2C Bus Num = 0  I2cDeviceList = 0x23
I2C Bus Num = 1  I2cDeviceList = 0x24

> > > > > > > > > > End   testPcf8574(). >>>>>>>>>>

End   scanI2cBuses(), tlfong01  2021apr03hkt1431, ...

> > > 

*/ to continue, ...*

---

*Appendix D - Full program listing of I2C Bus Scan program discussed in Appendix C above.*

[Pico I2C Bus Scan Program v0.1](https://penzu.com/p/0bcf4e5b)

---

*Appendix E - MicroPython ssd1306.py Listing v0.1*

[MicroPython ssd1306.py Listing v0.1](https://penzu.com/p/0bcf4e5b)

*Notes*

1. Windows 10 Thonny Program and Data Folder Locations:

   ***Program Folder*** = c: > user > AppData > Local > Programs
   > Thonny > Lib > site-packages > thonny

   ***Data Folder***    = c: > user > AppData > Roaming > Thonny
2. This ssd130.6py is only 150 python statement long, and contains two classes, one for I2C, an another for SPI.

---

*Appendix F - Rpi4B Python Hello World Program for SSD1306*

(8) [Rpi3B SSD1306 OLED I2C Interface Problem (with debugged Hello World program) - tlfong01 Rpi.SE Asked 2019dec21, Viewed 799 times](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106482/rpi3b-ssd1306-oled-i2c-interface-problem)

---

[image: ssd1306 hello world 01]

---

Comment: yes, I have the same OLED as you. 128x32 pixels I2C...

Comment: It appears that you have a rasp pi 4, I am doing this on windows with thonny, and this is the tutorial (one of many tutorials that i have tried to get the oled working) https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/oled-display-raspberry-pi-pico

Comment: perhaps, i should also mention that I have gotten the oled to work on a pro micro which is a copy of adafruit's pro micro

Comment: Ah, some misunderstanding here. As I said, the setup I showed was 2 years ago on Rpi4B Thonny. I am showing this for your reference and also to refresh my memory. I am glad that you are using Windows Thonny Micro Python and not ESP32 or AdaFruit Circuit Python. I am using both Rpi4B and Windows Thonny. So I will try to use Windows for you to compare and contrast, to troublsshoot.

Comment: here is one of the websites discussing adding a small delay that i mentioned earlier https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=4746

Comment: Ah, your successful testing on AdaFruit Pro Micro is very useful to our troubleshooting. So I won't guess your OLED is bad.

Comment: Just to confirm, so you have already installed the SSD1306 micropython library in your Pico?

Comment: yes, i have selected micropython ssd1306 and not circuitpythonand not ssd1327. the website suggests taking this to chat. should we?

Comment: i added a picture that might help you see what i chose, just in case.

Comment: Ha, your pic shows you have a long and thin SSD1306. But mine is a short, fat guy. I forgot the details of what I did two years ago. So I need to refresh my memory. Ah locking down lunch time. I need to go and eat.  See you later. PS - And let us move to chat room

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122642/discussion-between-zeno-and-tlfong01).