# Is There Support for 8-bit/4-bit parallel i/o bus (8080 or 6800) for LCD drivers?

Tags: driver, lcd

I'm looking at using a 240x128 LCD with a UC1608 chip.  Are there any packages that support parallel i/o with it? The UC1608 has support industry standard 3-wire, 4-wire serial bus (S9, S8, S8uc) and 8-bit/4-bit parallel bus (8080 or 6800).  However I would like to look into 8 bit i/o for speed, not so much for the display refreshing but because there are a 2 other SPI devices that require attention along with some computation.  So I don't want to spend much time with i/o on the display.

Anyone know of an existing library or C code to do this?

Thanks

Comment: how are you using the RPi in your project?

Comment: When I played with Arduino a couple of years ago, I played with HD44780 based line and graphics LCD.  At that time, there were many Arduino demo programs.  So I studied them and wrote my own programs.  Once you know how the things work, it is tedious but not difficult to write programs in C++ or python.  I guess UC1608 is of same complexity as HD44780.  I casually googled but could not find any 4/8 bit drivers or programs for Rpi.  As you say, it is easy to find I2C or SPI drivers, but they are a bit slow.  So one approach is to find Arduino C++ code and translate them into Rpi GPIO code.

Comment: Or you might start exploring from I2C/SPI modules: 3.8 " 240 * 128 Graphic Serial SPI Parallel COG Matrix LCD Module UC1608 Controller - US$28
( https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/33020523303.html )  For the HD44780 LCD modules, usually they piggyback an (easily removable) I2C/SPI 8 bit GPIO expander.  You can easily unplug the I2C/SPI module and connect 4/8 GIPO pins to the HD44780/UC1608, and then write your own python UC1608 "driver" program, with reference from Arduino library programs, or vendors 8080/6800 assembly language or C programs.

Comment: Even if you find a linux based UC1608 driver/kernel module, it might be tricky to build it.  You might like to skim the following post to see how complicated it is: (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98549/lcd-tft-screen-2-8-ili9341-spi-connect ).  You can also find in the post how I started adapting an I2C based LCD module into a Rpi 4 GPIO parallel pin based LCD module.  As I said earlier, this part is not that tricky, though tedious.