# Artillery [ ILI9341 ] 3.2" LCD Touch Screen White Display and Driver Problem

Tags: touchscreen, screen, driver, lcd

I bought this Artillery 3.2 Inch LCD Touch Screen Display Monitor: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32553185633.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dFky0Ok

But it only shows a white screen, so I probably need some driver to install? But I cannot figure out which one to install?

How can I find out these things?

Comment: did you connect the LCD to anything? ... if yes, then how did you connect it?

Answer (score -1):

***Question***

> (1) My [Artillery 3.2" SPI TFT touch screen](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32553185633.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dFky0Ok) only shows a white screen.
>
> (2) Why?
>
> (3) Do I need to install any driver?

---

***Answer***

*ILI9341 Touch Screen Interface*

[image: ili9341 test]

*White Screen Testing*

[image: white screen]

---

> (1) Your touch screen seems to use the ILI9341 driver (Ref 1)
>
> (2) You can google video tutorials to find more details (eg Ref 2, 4)
>
> (3) Depending on your config: Rpi3B+/Rpi4B stretch/buster version/released dates etc, and whether you are using 3/4 pin SPI or 16 GPIO pin connector mode, you might need to build your own driver/kernel module (Ref 3)

*A white screen usually means at least the back lit LED is working.  You need to install the driver to display. Ref 3 shows how to get the white screen and build a kernel.*

---

***References***

(1) [Artillery SPI TFT XPT2046 3.2 inch LCD touch screen monitor Module for Raspberry Pi3B/B+](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32553185633.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dFky0Ok)

(2) [TSC2046 XPT2046 TOUCH SCREEN ILI9341 2,008 views 2017oct01](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1XM4FYXCCE)

(3) [LCD TFT screen 2.8" ILI9341 SPI connect (How to build kernel/driver)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98549/lcd-tft-screen-2-8-ili9341-spi-connect)

(4) [How to create a simple LCD Touchscreen GUI Arduino, AdaFruit Library, ILI9341 240x320 - GreatScot 2018apr19 422k views, 12k Thumbs up 2018aug19](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SIo_Gv7K7Fo)

(5) [ILI9341 Touch LCD SPI Based Driver for Rpi3B+ stretch - juj 2019apr19](https://github.com/juj/fbcp-ili9341)

(6) [Rpi ILI9341 / XPT2046 SPI 3.2" Touch LCD Display - LCwiki](http://www.lcdwiki.com/3.2inch_RPi_Display)

(7) [How to install LCD driver](http://www.lcdwiki.com/res/PublicFile/How_to_install_the_LCD_driver_V1.2.pdf)

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - Wiring Notes v0.1*

[image: touch lcd wiring]

---

*End of Answer*

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try this soon!

Comment: @MuadDev，You are welcome.  Good luck and cheers!

Comment: @MuadDev, I just updated my answer with a new reference to a youtube tutorial on Arduino touch screen basics. You might find it good to build up touch screen newbie knowledge. The tutorial has an example using Arduino GPIO pins (not SPI). Actually I learned the basic theory and tricks in my Arduino days, messing around with small size monochrome LCDs. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SIo_Gv7K7Fo

Comment: thank you, I will have time to look at it in the weekend, will report back!