# How to use SPI touch screen with RPi?

Tags: spi, touchscreen

I bought a SPI TFT 2.4" display with a resistive touchscreen from eBay ([this one](https://www.ebay.com/itm/155136401497?var=455317340006)).

The screen is ILI9341 and works fine with Python and displays what I want. But how do I make use of the touch screen?

The PCB shows that the touch screen has got 5 pins: T_IRQ, T_DO, T_DIN, T_CS, T_CLK. From the Clock and CS pins presence I suspect that it's a SPI touchscreen? How do I make use of it? Ideally in Python. Any pointers?

Update: FWIW the touchscreen controller seems to be labelled XPT2046 if I'm not mistaken.

[image: SPI TFT 2.4" display with resistive touch screen]

Comment: @jsotola true, thanks for the comment. It seems to be labelled XPT2046 / 2021 if that helps.

Comment: yes,  it helps you ... do internet search for `XPT2046 raspberry` ... (2021 is probably a manufacture date stamp, 20th week of 2021)

Comment: These might help: (1) 
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98549/rpi3b-rpi4b-ili9341-xpt2046-spi-2-8-touch-tft-lcd-connection-driver-problem/98557#98557,
(2) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104600/artillery-ili9341-3-2-lcd-touch-screen-white-display-and-driver-problem/104610#104610