# white ili9341 display after short

Tags: pi-4, display

a few days ago i connected an ili9341 diaplay (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32961284118.html) to my raspberry pi , and after installing all the required python thinks , i runned a simple code and it just worked, but because i have a little 5V fan , that i tooked appart the connector , and i connected it to 3.3v , from mistake i shorted 3.3V and 5V line of the raspberry pi , and since then the screen is only white. What is broken now, the pi's spi interface or my display? (i have no way to test the display) and the raspberry pi is still working fine. I can also controll the gpio 22 just fine (the gpio thats connected to the displays backlight)

Comment: please draw a diagram of the connections ... show what you shorted together .... also, it is not possible to answer "What **is** broken", only "What **could be** broken"

Comment: I have a couple of posts on ILI9341 SPI TFT white screen. Here is an example you might find helpful. [1] Rpi3B/Rpi4B ILI9341 / XPT2046 SPI 2.8" Touch TFT LCD Connection / Driver Problem
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98549/rpi3b-rpi4b-ili9341-xpt2046-spi-2-8-touch-tft-lcd-connection-driver-problem/98557#98557. Good luck. Cheers.

Comment: Does your RPI boot if you remove the screen? You may have destoyed the power management IC by connecting 3.3V to 5V.

Comment: @Dougie the pi works just fine, the display doesnt

Comment: @jsotola the connection from the display to pi are as follows:
MISO-MISO
SCK-SCK
3.3V-VCC
GND-GND
CE0-CE
GPIO 24-DC
3.3v-LED