# I accidentaly lightly hit my bread board with my pi pico and ili9341 on it now the ili9341 is just white

Tags: display, pi-pico, wiring, breadboard, circuitpython

So i was in my chair and i clicked run script and when i got up i tripped and lightly hit my breadboard and then the screen (ili9341) went white. Before i hit it, it was working but not anymore. I tryed decconect the pico and put it back on then but it didn't work so i tryed *re downloading* (i only put it into boot mode then put the circuitpy file and didn't use the flash_nuke file) circuitpy and didn't work as well, wiring seems fine and i dont think i broke anything, i just almost touched it.

Note: Actually i fixed it. I think it was just a little connection problem. It does it often but i figured it all so it's good, thx for helping and the links in the reponse are helpfull so thx.

Comment: `i dont think i broke anything` - your description suggests otherwise

Comment: (1) Are you following any of the following tutorials? (a) https://bytesnbits.co.uk/raspberry-pi-pico-spi-lcd-display/
(b) https://www.instructables.com/Raspberry-Pi-Pico-CircuitPython-ILI9341/
(c) https://www.hackster.io/news/driving-an-ili9341-display-with-a-raspberry-pi-pico-8dd4ded042e1

Comment: you said that you hit it... that is definitely not *almost touched it* ... remove all components and wires from the breadboard ... build the circuit from the begining

Comment: (2) Or are you using Pico Thonny MicroPython and used its "manage package" tool and installed the following 6 years old PyPi ILI9341 package? https://github.com/tuupola/micropython-ili934x

Comment: (3) This ILI9341 library is good: AdaFruit ILI9341 CircuitPython Library - CircuitPython
https://docs.circuitpython.org/projects/ili9341/en/latest/index.html.

Comment: (4) ILI9341 LCD module white screen troubleshooting references: (a) ILI9341 LCD White after short - Asked 2 years ago Modified 2 years ago Viewed 122 times
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/121505/white-ili9341-display-after-short

(b) ILI9341 3.2 inch SPI Module ILI9341 SKU:MSP3218 Reference - : LcdWiki
http://www.lcdwiki.com/3.2inch_SPI_Module_ILI9341_SKU:MSP3218

Comment: The OP might like to confirm which ILI9341 LCD dsiplay model he has broken: 
(c) 3.2 inch SPI TFT LCD Screen - AliExpress
https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-3.2-inch-spi-tft-lcd-screen.html

Answer (score 0):

(A) *How to use Rpi Pico W to repair a broken ILI9341 LCD display module? - Selecting the module for testing.*

[image: ili9341 1]

[image: ili9341 2]

---

(B) *Rpi Pico W SPI Wiring Notes*

I am thinking of using PicoW's SPI #1 to connect to the ILI9341 LCD display module (GPIO 21~27).

[image: SPI 1]

---

(C) *ILI9341 SPI Wiring for troubleshooting*

[image: ili9341 spi wiring]

---

(D) PicoW SPI0 signal timing

[image: spi 1]

[image: spi 3]

[image: spi 4]

[image: spi 5]

---

[PicoW ili9341_SPI testing_2023mar26hkt1516 v01 program listing](https://penzu.com/p/f3aec205)

---

(E) PicoW SPI reading ILI9341 registers

[image: spi test 1]

[image: spi test 2]

---

(F) *PicoW ILI9341 Wiring Diagram*

(a) [Connect an SPI LCD Display to Your Raspberry Pi Pico Using MicroPython ILI9341 Driver - Bob, bytesNbits 2021dec29](https://bytesnbits.co.uk/raspberry-pi-pico-spi-lcd-display/)

(b) [ILI9341 TFT LCD Single Chip Driver 240 RGB x 320 datasheet v1.11 - ilitek](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/ILI9341.pdf)

[image: ili9341 wiring]

---

(G) RPi Pico/MicroPython + ILI9341 SPI Display with Touch - Rdagger

(a) [RPi Pico/MicroPython + ILI9341 SPI Display with Touch, using rdagger/micropython-ili9341 - Hello Rpi, 2021mar06](http://helloraspberrypi.blogspot.com/2021/03/rpi-picomicropython-ili9341-spi-display.html)

(b) [rdagger/micropython-ili9341 (MicroPython ILI9341Display & XPT2046 Touch Screen Driver) - 2022sep03](https://github.com/rdagger/micropython-ili9341)

---

(H) *ILI9341 LCD Touch Screen Setup and Troubleshooting*

[image: ouch screen signal pin wiring]

(a) [RPi Pico/MicroPython + ILI9341 SPI Display with Touch, using rdagger/micropython-ili9341 - HelloRpi 2021mar06](http://helloraspberrypi.blogspot.com/2021/03/rpi-picomicropython-ili9341-spi-display.html)

(b) [ILI9341 2.4inch SPI Module ILI9341 SKU:MSP2402 - LcdWiki](http://www.lcdwiki.com/2.4inch_SPI_Module_ILI9341_SKU:MSP2402)

(c) [ILI9341 2.4inch SPI Module ILI9341 SKU:MSP2402 User Manual - LcdWiki](http://www.lcdwiki.com/res/MSP2402/2.4inch_SPI_Module_MSP2402_User_Manual_EN.pdf)

*Touch screen signal line wiring*

```
10  T_CLK   Touch SPI bus clock signal
11  T_CS    Touch screen chip select signal, low level enable
12  T_DIN   Touch SPI bus input
13  T_DO    Touch SPI bus output
14  T_IRQ   Touch screen interrupt signal, low level when touch is detected
```

---

(I) *So I repeated the OP's white screen*

[image: white screen 1]

---

*PicoW ILI9341 Wiring Scheme v0.1*

[image: ili9341 wiring 1]

---

(J) *ILI9341 White Screen Troubleshooting Suggestion*

[image: rgb565 colours]

---

*ILI9341 White Screen Troubleshooting*

(a) [framebuf - microphon.org](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/framebuf.html)

(b) [newdigate / rgb565_colors colour name definitions - github](https://github.com/newdigate/rgb565_colors)

(c) [Color Depth (65k, 262k, 16.7M Colors) - focusLeds](https://focuslcds.com/color-depth-65k-262k-16-7m-colors/)

(d) [Multi Thread Coding on the Raspberry Pi Pico in MicroPython - Threads, Locks and problems!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1q0EaTkztIs)

(e) [getis/pi-pico-spi-lcd-ili9341-st7789 Publ](https://github.com/getis/pi-pico-spi-lcd-ili9341-st7789)ic

---

```
framebuf — frame buffer manipulation - micropython.org
This module provides a general frame buffer which can be used to create bitmap images, which can then be sent to a display.

class FrameBuffer
The FrameBuffer class provides a pixel buffer which can be drawn upon with pixels, lines, rectangles, ellipses, polygons, text and even other FrameBuffers. It is useful when generating output for displays.

For example:

import framebuf

# FrameBuffer needs 2 bytes for every RGB565 pixel
fbuf = framebuf.FrameBuffer(bytearray(100 * 10 * 2), 100, 10, framebuf.RGB565)

fbuf.fill(0)
fbuf.text('MicroPython!', 0, 0, 0xffff)
fbuf.hline(0, 9, 96, 0xffff)
```

---

(K) *XPT2046 Touch Screen Controller*

[image: xpt2046 summary]

*Touch screen signal line wiring*

```
10  T_CLK   Touch SPI bus clock signal
11  T_CS    Touch screen chip select signal, low level enable
12  T_DIN   Touch SPI bus input
13  T_DO    Touch SPI bus output
14  T_IRQ   Touch screen interrupt signal, low level when touch is detected
```

[XPT2046 Touch Screen Controller Datasheet - XPTek 2007may](https://ldm-systems.ru/f/doc/catalog/HY-TFT-2,8/XPT2046.pdf)

---

[rdagger/micropython-ili9341 /xpt2046.py (Serial interface for XPT2046 Touch Screen Controller) - Rdagger](https://github.com/rdagger/micropython-ili9341/blob/master/xpt2046.py)

---

[rdagger xpt2046.py program listing](https://penzu.com/p/d7cb1865)

---