# Pico LCD Display

Tags: pi-pico, lcd

is the screen in the link compatible with Raspberry Pi Pico?  https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/2.4inch_LCD_Module
I will be happy if you can tell me the circuit diagram and sample code

Comment: does the RPi Pico support SPI?

Comment: A good practice (or actually a requirement of Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange guideline) is to search for an answer yourself before asking it hear and to share in the question your prior effort. Could you please comment on the search you've done to answer the questions?

Comment: This might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/142562/i-accidentaly-lightly-hit-my-bread-board-with-my-pi-pico-and-ili9341-on-it-now-t

Comment: @tlfong01 Thank you very much

Comment: @MEnsar55. You are welcome. Your WaveShare ILI9341 2.4" LCD is exactly what I have been doing. Feel free to ask me other newbie questions. Cheers.