# ILI9341 Touchscreen Error

Tags: touchscreen, screen, lcd, pi-pico-w

I'm using a Raspberry Pi Pico and an ili9341 touchscreen. To the codes below;

```
import machine
import ili9341

# Set up the SPI bus
spi = machine.SPI(0, baudrate=10000000, miso=machine.Pin(16), mosi=machine.Pin(19), 
sck=machine.Pin(18))

# Set up the LCD display
lcd = ili9341.ILI9341(spi, 240, 320, cs=machine.Pin(17), dc=machine.Pin(20))

# Clear the screen
lcd.clear()

# Write "Hello World" to the screen
lcd.write("Hello World")

# Display the screen
lcd.display()
```

i am getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 8, in 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ILI9341'

I downloaded the .py file in the link.
https://github.com/rdagger/micropython-ili9341/blob/master/ili9341.py

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because in effect it is a duplicate of https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/143129/ili9341-tft-display

Comment: @joan I asked for the code and circuit diagram in the previous thread, but I couldn't find the answer I wanted.  Now I'm getting an error and I opened this thread to resolve it.

Comment: You should have supplied the information requested for the original question.  You are wasting your time and our time.

Comment: this might help: https://peppe8o.com/adding-external-modules-to-micropython-with-raspberry-pi-pico/

Comment: this might also help: https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rpi3B/Rpi4B ILI9341 / XPT2046 SPI 2.8" Touch TFT LCD Connection / Driver Problem](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98549/rpi3b-rpi4b-ili9341-xpt2046-spi-2-8-touch-tft-lcd-connection-driver-problem)

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is occurring due to an installation problem with ili9341. Make sure that you have downloaded and installed the ili9341 library properly.